# Running command prompt using webapi but does not have permission

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do a web api which allows my to start/stop/reset my application pools and sites inside IIS.

Currently, I have tested that running administration level Visual studio allows me to run my code flawlessly. But once I'm not running visual studio with administration level privileged, or even deployed to IIS and run as a test service, my method inside breaks.

A little overview of how it is done is I get a Process to run CMD which utilizes the appcmd to list and reset the iis connections.

```
            private List<SiteModels> GetSiteModels()
                    {
                        Process process = new Process();
                        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized,
                            FileName = "cmd.exe",
                            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\",
                            Arguments = "/K appcmd list sites & exit",
                            Verb = "runas",
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true
                        };
                        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                        process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

                        List<SiteModels> sitesModelList = new List<SiteModels>();
                        string tempString = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        process.WaitForExit();
                        foreach (var line in tempString.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        {
                            SiteModels sitesModel = new SiteModels();

                            string pattern = "SITE \"(?<SiteName>.*?)\"[\\s\\S]*?id:(?<Id>.*?),[\\s\\S]*?bindings:(?<Bindings>.*?),[\\s\\S]*?state:(?<State>.*?)\\)";
                            Regex regexPattern = new Regex(pattern);
                            Match match = regexPattern.Match(line);

                            if (match.Success)
                            {
                                sitesModel.SiteName = match.Groups["SiteName"].Value.Trim();
                                sitesModel.Id = int.Parse(match.Groups["Id"].Value.Trim());
                                sitesModel.Bindings = match.Groups["Bindings"].Value.Trim();
                                sitesModel.State = match.Groups["State"].Value.Trim();

                                sitesModelList.Add(sitesModel);
                            }
                        }
                        return sitesModelList;
                    }
```

Comment: Yeah so run the app pool under a user who has those permissions?

Comment: already running it under administrator... still getting the permission error

Comment: You could use a WMI query to get sites list instead of start a process. Start point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wmi+iis)